# Whenever I dismiss the keyboard while keyboard is open my whole code breaks Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Whenever I use FocusManager or FocusScope.of(context) my code breaks and the controller.loading values are ignored.

> When the keyboard is not open the code works perfectly fine

and

> even if I place the FocusManager After the await it works perfectly fine

But

> The Focus Manager or FocusScopr.of(context) break when placed like below

```
void resetPassword() async {
      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(); // Placed Here the code behaves very diffrently

      try {
 FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(); // Also breaks here or at any place behind the await function
        controller.changeErrorStatus(false);

        if (emailController.text.isEmpty) {
          controller.changeErrorStatus(true);

          controller.changeErrorMessage(
              "An Error Occurred, Email Field cannot be left blank.");
          controller.startLoading(false);

          return;
        }
        controller.startLoading(true);
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

        // await FirebaseAuth.instance
        //     .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: emailController.text.trim())
        //     .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));

        controller.startLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        controller.changeErrorStatus(true);
        controller.startLoading(false);

        controller.changeErrorMessage("An Error Occurred, $e");
        
      }
    }
```

It Works Like this

```
 
      try {
        controller.changeErrorStatus(false);

        if (emailController.text.isEmpty) {
          controller.changeErrorStatus(true);

          controller.changeErrorMessage(
              "An Error Occurred, Email Field cannot be left blank.");
          controller.startLoading(false);

          return;
        }
        controller.startLoading(true);
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();  // If Focus Scope is here everything works Fine

        // await FirebaseAuth.instance
        //     .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: emailController.text.trim())
        //     .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));

        controller.startLoading(false);
```

Also tried calling it from the onTap function and it still breaks

```
onTap:(){ 
 FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
resetPassword();
}
```

The controller.isLoading values are right but the button disregards then for I don't what reason

```
Obx(
              () => Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: size.width * 0.8,
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: mainController.isLoading.value
                        ? AppColors().secHalfGrey
                        : AppColors().primaryBlue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: mainController.isLoading.value
                    ? Lottie.asset("assets/jsons/atom-loader.json")
                    : Text(
                        buttonText,
                        style: context.textTheme.displayMedium,
                      ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: what is the error when you use it in try catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was messing around and found the answer

> I used the onTapOutside of the TextFormField and used the

```
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
```

The Function is

```
onTapOutside: (event) {
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
},
```

I hope it helps anyone who is facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

Instead of :

```
 FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
```

Comment: doesn't work either ways.

Comment: write this line in your onTap() : FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); before resetPassword() method call. and remove focus code from everywhere except here.

Comment: tried that didn't work as well.

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Found the solution. Thank you for your help.